# Excel.Range.set_Value causing "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

Tags: c#, excel, wpf, interop

This error occurs only in Microsoft Excel 2007. In Excel 2010 works correctly.

```
_range.set_Value(Missing.Value, values);
```

Are there any string lenght limitation?? Is that a limitation of Excel 2007? Are there some workaround??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I found that it was a problem length. I can't add a cell with more than 8192 chars. It's a limitation of Excel 2007. No problems with Excel 2010

Answer (score 0):

Does your values array contain any DateTime objects? I have received this same error when using this method to push DateTimes that are outside of Excel's acceptable range.

Comment: No there weren't any DateTimes.
At the end I found that it was a problem length. I can't add a cell with more than 8192 chars. It's a limitation of Excel 2007.
No problems with Excel 2010